# Karate framework: avoid counting auxiliar .features as real tests

Tags: karate

I have only one test:

```
Feature:
  Background:
   * call read('../rollback-database.feature')

  ...test steps...
```

Note that the feature is calling other feature.

When tests finish I got:

```
 Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.006 sec
```

What can I do to avoid counting the auxiliary feature as a test?

I'm using Karate Junit Runner.

Thanks in advance.